# ffmpeg Python command only runs once in PM2 environment

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pm2, ffmpeg-python

PM2 is running as a `web` user. ffmpeg was installed native to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using `sudo apt install ffmpeg`. The Python version is 3.6. The software uses [ffmpeg-python@0.1.17](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).

The applications spawned produce no errors. When the ffmpeg code executes for the first time, we see an output and the ffmpeg process completes the task as expected.

All subsequent requests stall on the next ffmpeg execution. No output. No return from the ffmpeg process. No errors. The PM2 process does not error out. The application log stalls on the ffmpeg command as though it is hung.

**What is the root cause?** Any help is deeply appreciated.

Furthermore, what are the reasons PM2 hangs on a subprocess (like ffmpeg)?

Here is the code:

```
class ImageHelper:

def __init__(self):
    pass

@classmethod
def create_thumb_from_video_ffmpeg(cls, input_video_file_path,
                                   output_image_path,
                                   scale_width,
                                   scale_height
                                   ):
    """
        This function is used to create the thumb image
        from a source video file.
        We are using a python wrapper/library for FFMPEG
    """
    try:
        if Functions.get_attribute_env('ENVIRONMENT') == 'prod':

            out, err = (
                ffmpeg
                    .input(input_video_file_path, ss="00:00:00.001")
                    .filter('scale', scale_width, scale_height)
                    .output(output_image_path, vframes=1, loglevel='quiet')
                    .overwrite_output()
                    .run(capture_stdout=True)
            )
            print("We only see this once!")
        else:
            out, err = (
                ffmpeg
                    .input(input_video_file_path, ss="00:00:00.001")
                    .filter('scale', scale_width, scale_height)
                    .output(output_image_path, vframes=1)
                    .overwrite_output()
                    .run(capture_stdout=True)
            )
            print("We only see this once!")

        if err:
            if Functions.get_attribute_env('ENVIRONMENT') != 'prod':
                print('ffmpeg video thumb', err)
            else:
                Functions.logger_function(str(err))
            raise Exception(err)
        else:
            return output_image_path

    except Exception as e:
        if Functions.get_attribute_env('ENVIRONMENT') != 'prod':
            print('in thumb exception', e)
        else:
            Functions.logger_function(str(e))
        raise Exception(e)
```

Comment: Did you check the active processes after it hangs to see if your `ffmpeg` command is among them?

Comment: Have you tried stopping the `ffmpeg` process after it completes the task before you launch it again?

Comment: Did you try to start your application without PM2 and check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth to anyone with a subprocess problem... the solution turned out to be attributed to the a badly done .env implementation. When we finally recreated the .env, the problem went away. I actually recommended to my team that we use Anaconda for our Python env and that did the trick. :'D

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the `ffmpeg` process is running while the sequential request is made or not. If it is, you may want to make sure the process is closed after the first completion so it can start again for the sequential request.

Answer (score 0):

Processes spawned by `apache` or `nginx` will have limits on how long they execute and will be killed automatically. In those cases you'll probably want to have the script triggered to run *outside* of the web process pool, eg. something like:

```
setsid /usr/bin/python3 my_script.py
```